# Square root of Chi-square distribution tends to $N(0,1)$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The question requires to show that $\sqrt{2\chi^2_n}-\sqrt{2n}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, which I dont know how to proceed.

The question also has a first part asking to show $\frac{\chi^2_n-n}{\sqrt{2n}}$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$, and it's straightforward by CLT. I am thinking if there is any connection between the two parts, however still have no idea.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very similar question was asked here, with a different method of solution:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832422/limiting-distribution/832435#832435

Answer (score 3):

You can use the univariate delta method: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). First we start with a situation where the CLT holds. In your case you can represent a $\chi^2_n$ variable as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2  $ with ${Z_i}$ iid $N(0,1).$ Then $\mu:=E(Z_i^2)=1$ and $\sigma^2:=Var(Z_i^2)=2.$ Let $B_n= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} Z_i^2.$ Then the CLT shows $ \sqrt n{[B_n-\mu]}\to N(0,\sigma^2)$ in distribution.

Now we use the transformation $g(x)=\sqrt{2x}$ on the statistic $B_n $ and investigate the asymptotic distribution of $g(B_n).$ The univariate delta method says we can conclude:
$$ \sqrt{n}[g(B_n)-g(\mu)]\to N(0,\sigma^2[g^{'}(\mu)] ^2  )$$

Now $g^{'}(x)=1/\sqrt{2x}   $ so we have
$$ \sqrt{n}[\sqrt{2\chi_n^2/n}-\sqrt{2}]\to N(0,1 )$$ and that is what you wanted.